# How do I pass Properties or .Settings to a function?

Tags: c#, .net, syntax

I'm currently using .Settings files to store level data (Level1.settings, Level2.settings) in a WinForms application. Please nevermind why I would do that :) I'm currently reading each level with a different function, because I can't figure out how to pass to a function.

In my application I have:

```
AppTitle
  Properties
    Level1.settings
    Level2.settings
```

I am currently reading them with separate functions, for example:

```
void readLevel1() 
{ 
   levelMessage = Properties.Level1.Default.WelcomeMessage; 
}
```

In this example, how could I pass "Level1" as a parameter to the function?

I would have preferred something like:

```
void readLevel(String identifier)
{
  levelMessage = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[identifier].Default.WelcomeMessage;
}
```

But I'm getting syntax errors on "Default" says, 'string does not contain a definition for 'Default' and not extension method 'Default' accepting a first argument of String can be found'. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

New Info:
OK I have been banging my head on the wall all day and here's what I came up with, that seems to work:

```
Configuration config = ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(ConfigurationUserLevel.None);
ConfigurationSection cs = config.SectionGroups["applicationSettings"].Sections["AppTitle.Properties.Level1"];
ClientSettingsSection css = (ClientSettingsSection)cs;
String s = css.Settings.Get("WelcomeMessage").Value.ValueXml.InnerText;
```

If anyone knows a better way please let me know! Using InnerText feels like a hack.

Thank you Ann for trying to help!

Comment: Regarding your new question:  have you tried casting your variable `cs` to `Level1`?  I don't know that that will work because I haven't tried it, but it might.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am going to assume that `Level1` and `Level2` have all the same properties with all the same definitions.

In that case, you could create an interface that both `Level1` and `Level2` would implement.  You could then define your settings-reading method like this:

```
void ReadLevel(ILevelSettings settingsInstance)
{
   levelMessage = settingsInstance.WelcomeMessage;
}
```

You would call it like this:

```
ReadLevel(Properties.Level1.Default);
```

If the generated classes for `Level1` and `Level2` are partial classes (and I can't remember if they are) this should be easy to implement.

**ETA:  Partial class demonstration:**

The `partial` keyword on a class definition means that the definition of the class is not necessarily all within one source code file.  You can have others.

So you can create your own source code file, call it something like "Level1.partial.cs", and use this code:

```
 namespace AppTitle.Properties
 {
     internal sealed partial class Level1 : ILevelSettings
     {
         // any additional functions or properties that you would like
         // your Level1 class to have.
     }
 }
```

(Disclaimer:  that was from memory.  I omitted the `using` statements.)

At compile time, the compiler will gather up all the definitions of class `Level1` that have the same namespace and modifying keywords (internal, sealed) and build them into a single class, mixing the generated methods and properties and any ones you added.

You can thereby make the generated `Level1` and `Level2` classes inherit from an interface (or even a base class), even though most of the class definition was generated.  You can regenerate it at any time without affecting the code you added, because it's in a different file.

Comment: I see the definition is: internal sealed partial class Level1 { .... I'm guessing if I try to modify it in code by trying to make it implement an interface, every time I use Visual Studio's editor to change a property I'll lose it.. Its almost like I need to be able to enumerate the classes in my App Properties

Comment: No, actually you can do it in a separate file.  That's the beauty of a partial class!  I'll add code to demonstrate.

Comment: If I use this, do I have to implement a new class for each level? I really just wanted to pass in the classes that were already there. Not to sound unappreciative but help me out if I was going to do that, wouldn't I just not use AppSettings and use classes to store my config? I'm guessing I just don't get it.

Comment: Ann, I feel like a problem is that I can't find out what base class to use for the function parameter, that would enable me to just pass "Properties.Level1" as the parameter..?

Comment: @DanChase I believe `Properties.Level1` is the name of the class. If you need the actual object, you'd need to pass `Properties.Level1.Default`.  That would give you an object to pass.

Comment: Also, the base class is `System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsBase`.  However, if you make that the function parameter, the function won't know about your specific settings properties, which is why I suggested making your settings classes inherit from an interface and using the interface as the function parameter.

Comment: But I'm thinking now that maybe the core of the problem is that you have multiple classes with exactly the same definition, whereas what you really need is multiple instances of one settings class.  Not sure how to implement that within the built-in Settings framework, though.  I can give it some thought if you'd like.